# Do I need negative covid test for transit through France (CDG)

Tags: international-travel, france, covid-19, attestation

I have booked Santiago, Chile (SCL) - Paris (CDG) - Manchester, UK (MAN) for Dec 30. Both arriving and departing flights from France are in terminal 2E at Charles de Gaulle.
However, it's not clear to me if I need a covid test or not.

The airline, Air France, gives me this message (my bolds) https://www.airfrance.cl/CL/es/common/page_flottante/hp/news-air-traffic-air-france.htm

> NEW CONDITIONS OF ENTRY IN FRANCE
> NEW ANTIGENIC TEST ACCEPTATION
> Updated on 24 December 2020, 03:00 PM Paris local time
> Air France has been informed of the new decree **specifying the conditions of entry or transit in France** and Overseas Territories.
> This particularly concerns the acceptance of antigenic tests, which must now enable the detection of N protein of SARS-CoV-2.
> These new conditions only concern antigenic tests, there is no change concerning other tests such as PCR or RT-Lamp.
> The list of all tests accepted is available on the following French Health website

However, going by this info
https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/

> - If you are transiting for less than 24 hours in an international zone;

I am led to believe I don't need anything more than a couple of declarations to be on my way? The transit is around 5 hours. This is my first time flying though and I'm not sure what counts as an international zone. I suppose  by not exiting terminal 2E I am never really entering France?

I will be using my Italian passport by the way, and I must enter the UK before Dec 31st at 11pm due to brexit, in case anyone was wondering about this ridiculous trip I'm forced to make in such convoluted times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you booked this travel on 1 ticket, and you stay in the transit (airside) you won't need a test. If these were 2 separate tickets, and you have to leave the transit to get your bags and check them in again you would need a test.

But what keeps you away from testing?
First you wouldn't need to worry if you need a test in France or not, and second it would be safer for every one...

Answer (score 3):

The [page you linked to](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/) states:

> In addition, for travellers over 11 years of age:

> A. If you are arriving from a country on the list below, even if you are in transit, or if you have been there in the last 30 days you must present a negative test result carried out less than 72 hours before boarding. You will not be allowed to board without this document.
>
> > Algeria, Bahrain, China, Democratic Republic of the Congo, Ecuador, Iraq, Iran, Israel, Lebanon, Morocco, Panama, South Africa, Russia, Turkey, United Arab Emirates, Ukraine, United States and Zimbabwe.

> B. If you are coming from another country, you are strongly recommended to present a negative test result, carried out less than 72 hours before departure, upon your arrival in France. If you do not have this result, you will have to take a test at your airport of arrival.

So if you have not been to any of the listed countries in the last 30 days (or the UK in the last 14 days), you do not need to have taken a test before leaving, whether in transit or not. It’s unclear to me whether you will have to get tested at the airport if in transit. In any case, taking a test before travelling seems like the safest option for everyone involved.

Note however that the [transit through France means you will need to self-isolate for 10 days when arriving in the UK](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-travel-corridors).